# Nightwatch.js: How to run a log-in script before running the test suite

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

Is there a way where I can Run a script to run a website and perform log in etc. and before running a test suite using Nightwatch JS? I have tried to use beforeeach hook in global.js, but so far failed to make it work. If there is a solution for this? I will appreciate if you can respond with examples.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I believe the question is self explanatory. I could post a lot of garbage scripts here which would add zero value to the question. I asked the question because I am stuck, so it would be more appropriate if I could get an answer to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Then don't post a bunch of garbage scripts. You are describing existing attempts and that they failed but given us no details. We aren't going to guess what you did because that's a waste of our time. Post a [mcve] and a description of how it failed, including any error messages, etc. if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we figured out a solution. In the below snippet the Globals.js file is the common login module that we need to run before running each test script.

```
 const loginPage = require("../../Globals.js");
// START ------> Import Login Module from Globals.js
module.exports = {
  beforeEach: function (client) {
    loginPage.login(client);
 },
```